# Parsing Data of data from a file

Tags: c++

i have this project due however i am unsure of how to parse the data by the word, part of speech and its definition... I know that i should make use of the tab spacing to read it but i have no idea how to implement it. here is an example of the file

```
Recollection    n.  The power of recalling ideas to the mind, or the period within which things can be recollected; remembrance; memory; as, an event within my recollection.
Nip n.  A pinch with the nails or teeth.
Wodegeld    n.  A geld, or payment, for wood.
Xiphoid a.  Of or pertaining to the xiphoid process; xiphoidian.
```

NB: Each word and part of speech and definition is one line in a text file.

Comment: Have you heard about `regex`?

Comment: You could use `std::getline(file, word, '\t')` ... etc [std::getline](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

Comment: What have you tried doing?

Comment: @Galik how would that work? could i get an example?

Answer (score 0):

If you can be sure that the definition will always follow the first period on a line, you could use an implementation like this. But it will break if there are ever more than 2 periods on a single line.

```
string str = "";
vector<pair<string,string>> v; // <word,definition>

while(getline(fileStream, str, '.')) {    // grab line, deliminated '.'
  str[str.length() - 1] = "";    // get rid of n, v, etc. from word
  v.push_back(make_pair<string,string>(str,""));    // push the word
  getline(fileStream, str, '.');    // grab the next part of the line
  v.back()->second = str;    // push definition into last added element
}

for(auto x : v) {    // check your results
  cout << "word -> " << x->first << endl;
  cout << "definition -> " << x->second << endl << endl; 
}
```

The better solution would be to learn **Regular Expressions**. It's a complicated topic but absolutely necessary if you want to learn how to parse text efficiently and properly:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/